# Error with libPods.a

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I'm working with an old project in the new XCode 6 GM.

I ran `pod install` with a target `platform :ios, '6.0'` set then opened the workspace created and selected "6.0" as "Deployment target" for the project but the build failed with this warning:

`Pods was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libPods.a' because its architectures 'x86_64' didn't contain all required architectures 'i386'`

And this error:

`ld: library not found for -lPods`

The `libPods.a` is being displayed in red color in the project navigation bar.

What could be causing that?

Answer (score 0):

I just used `pod install` on an old project under the new Xcode 6 GM and it worked, check the `libPods.a` is in your finder folder and retry the `pod install` command without a target.

Comment: Actually it seems to be an architecture problem (i386, x64)

Comment: My target says: `platform :ios, '6.1'`